# Slow code using searching in data table

Tags: c#, xml, performance, ado.net

I have 2 data tables (1 from xml , other from database) which I am trying to compare. Tables are related with a composite primary key. I am trying to execute the following code. With around 5000 rows it takes more than a minute.

I tried using datatable.Select() for same bt of no use. Can someone suggest how to optimize the code and what I am missing here ?

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    DataTable dtXmlRecs = new DataTable("records");

    dtXmlRecs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("A", typeof(int)));
    dtXmlRecs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("B", typeof(string))); 
    dtXmlRecs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("C", typeof(int)));
    dtXmlRecs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("D", typeof(int)));
    dtXmlRecs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("E", typeof(string)));
    dtXmlRecs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("F", typeof(Int16)));
    dtXmlRecs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("H", typeof(byte))); 
    dtXmlRecs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("I", typeof(decimal))); 
    dtXmlRecs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("J", typeof(decimal))); 
    dtXmlRecs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("K", typeof(decimal))); 


    dtXmlRecs.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { 
              dtXmlRecs.Columns["E"]
            , dtXmlRecs.Columns["F"]
            , dtXmlRecs.Columns["H"] };


    ds.Tables.Add(dtXmlRecs);

    ds.ReadXml(@"c:\myxmlfile.xml");

    DataTable dtOldData = objBAL.getOldData(
                     ds.Tables["records"].Rows[0]["B"].ToString());

    dtOldData.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] 
                 { dtOldData.Columns["E"]
                 , dtOldData.Columns["F"]
                 , dtOldData.Columns["H"] };
    ds.Tables.Add(dtOldData);

    ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("OldNewData", 
                     new DataColumn[] 
                     { dtOldData.Columns["E"]
                     , dtOldData.Columns["F"]
                     , dtOldData.Columns["H"] }, 
           new DataColumn[]
                     { dtXmlRecs.Columns["E"]
                     , dtXmlRecs.Columns["F"]
                     , dtXmlRecs.Columns["H"]}
                     , false));
    DataRow drXml;
    DataRow drCircle;
    decimal diff;
    for (int i = 0; i < dtXmlRecs.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        drXml = dtXmlRecs.Rows[i];
        //this function call is very slow.
        drCircle = drXml.GetParentRow("OldNewData"); 

        if (drCircle != null)

        {

    //code goes here

        }
   }
```

Thanks..

Comment: Can you indicate for each of the columns in your primary key (E, F, H) how many distinct values you have? (by average if an exact count is difficult)

Comment: Dear rene- as of now, there are around **5000** records, Apporoximate distincts are - E (2500) , F (2), H (1).  Since this is current scenario, I have future scope of more than 1 value of H.

Comment: Can you check if you gain anything if you put the F column FIRST in your primarykey?

Comment: So there are around 5000 records in both dtXmlRecs and dtOldData? I just tried the same code and for 5000 records it is under a second. Performance degrades only after I have 500000 records in either table.

Comment: Nothing worked ... did the same at sql server (sent xml to server then compared). Working fine. thanks all